# host configuration is enabled by unknown instead of site administrator

Tags: apache-2.4, web-server, ubuntu-18.04

I changed an Apache reverse proxy configuration, to add a new hostname.

I don't usually manage webservers / proxies, though I basically replicated the existing structure:

- created a separate `mysite.com.conf` file with the relevant `VirtualHost` directives inside the `sites-available` folder
- created a symlink named `mysite.com.conf` in the `sites-enabled` folder pointing toward the new file
- restarted Apache with `systemctl restart apache2`

Everything works as expected, the website is reachable and such. There's only a small thing that puzzles me: if I do `a2query -s` I can see the new host I added in the command output.

But, while all the others are listed like:

- [www.example1.com](http://www.example1.com) (enabled by site administrator)
- [www.example2.com](http://www.example2.com) (enabled by site administrator)
- ...

Mine is instead:

- mysite.com **(enabled by unknown)**

From where does that `unknown` come from and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Debian (and so, on Ubuntu as well), the preferred way to create sites is to create them in the `/etc/apache2/sites-available` directory (named `something.conf`), then run the `a2ensite something` command, where `something` is the name of the config file without the extension.

Similarly, enabling config snippets (these are in the `/etc/apache2/conf-available` directory) and modules (from the `mods-available` directory) should be done by using the `a2enconf` and `a2enmod` commands.

These commands have a corresponding "disable" pair, named `a2dissite`, `a2disconf` and `a2dismod`, and they write a status to the `/var/lib/apache2` directory, from which the `a2query` script reads the info. If there is a config file which doesn't have an entry in `/var/lib/apache`, then it is there by "unknown".